# Joda-Time - Creating new instance of LocalDateTime returns incorrect current time

Tags: android, jodatime

When I create a new instance of `LocalDateTime` and try to get the current hour, it is off by exactly 4 hours.

For example my code will be as follows:

```
LocalDateTime mReminderTime = new LocalDateTime();
int mHourOfDay = mReminderTime.getHourOfDay();
```

The system time on the phone/tablet will be 19:00 while `mHourOfDay` will be 23:00. I have been testing these on physical devices.

I have also tried the following code with the same results:

```
LocalDateTime mReminderTime = LocalDateTime.now();
int mHourOfDay = mReminderTime.getHourOfDay();
```

My timezone is EST, which is -4:00 of GMT. I believe this is exactly the issue. The LocalDateTime is instantiating at 0:00 GMT causing `mHourOfDay` to be precisely 4 hours ahead of the system time.

My question: How do I get the `LocalDateTime` to initialize at EST via detecting the current timezone of the device? I don't want to set LocalDateTime to specifically use -4:00 GMT in case the user changes timezones. Right now I have a workaround solution using the `Calendar` as follows:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
mReminderTime = new LocalDateTime(cal);
```

I was hoping to rely fully on Joda-Time, thus I wanted a solution that avoids the `Calendar`. If it helps, I am using this library to import Joda-Time into my project: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android